# Django inventory app, where to override save for quantity control?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, inventory, inventory-management

I have 'three' models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

class Operation(models.Model):
    operation_type_choices = (
        ('sell', 'Sell'),
        ('donation', 'Donation'),
    )
    book = models.ManyToManyField(Book, through = 'BookOperation') 
    operation_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=operation_type_choices)

class BookOperation(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    operation = models.ForeignKey(Operation)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to know in what model should I override the save() function to manage when a operation is 'sell', so the book.quantity should lower and when it's 'donation' it should rise.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in the Model you have the `quantity` attribute.
Take a look to [Signals Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/) to avoid override the `save()` method and use a `post_save` or `pre_save` method.

Answer (score 0):

While the modelling could be done in other ways too, I suppose you picked the one that was most meaningful for your requirements.

Given the specific models, I would assume that `Operation` and `BookOperation` models are both used when an 'operation' is made. This of course would depend on how you would structure the forms later on as well as the relative views. But given this, it seems that either of them is good enough to use for the `save()` function.

By the looks of it I would certainly *not* use the `Book` model as this is your master model and it is not immediately affected by an 'operation' transaction.